# Clash of clans linking problem

Tags: achievements, technical-issues, clash-of-clans

I have two Google accounts, and I play coc on my iPad. I linked my new phone using my first Google account through the iPad, but now I want to cancel the link with my first account and instead add the link to the second gmail account because I use that account more.

I have written several emails to the Supercell community, but there has been no reply from their side.

Can I instead transfer my achievements or something from my first gmail account to the second?

Comment: There appears to be some confusion here. Google+ accounts cannot be linked on an iPad. Either you're linking to a Game Center account, or you're using an Android device instead.

Comment: @Thebluefish Thats what i am saying i linked my coc account first to my ipad then my new phone but with the wrong account on my new phone i wanted it to be linked with another gmail account which i use more.

Comment: You can create an appleid with the same email address as your google account.  On android the "google id" you sign into for the game can be different from the one you are using for e.g. gmail. The same is true on the  iPad... the "itunes" or "primary" appleid can be different from the one you use in GameCenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking a Clash of Clans village with your Google+ account is a permanent process. You cannot unlink an account from the Google+ account, and you cannot transfer it to a different Google+ account.

The best suggestion I can offer is to use the in-game support to request that SuperCell transfer it for you or unlink it from the unwanted Google+ account. With Clash of Clans open, go to Settings -> "Help and Support" at the bottom -> "Report an issue" at the bottom-right -> "Other Problem". This will open up an email to SuperCell with important info about your village, you can ask them about your issue there.

Other than that, there is no way to accomplish what you're asking for.

Comment: The OP stated he was using his Google account with an iPad which implies he has actually created an AppleID using his Gmail account for the  email.  This is perfectly possible... and guess what, you can change your AppleID email to point somewhere completely different.